# jQuery Select all Disabled texboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to select ALL of the disabled textboxes and add a Class to them, how do I do this in jQuery

Comment: So... there is no 'textbox' type or element. There's a textarea element, an input of type text and an input of type checkbox. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[type=textbox]:disabled').addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: He said textbox, not checkbox.  I updated your answer for you.  Cheers!